# IMAP responds with LOGIN BAD invalid command

Tags: sockets, ssl, client, client-server, imap

I'm trying to write an IMAP client in C#. I'm able to connect to the host but unable to get expected responses after that (when using, for example, commands like LOGIN or CAPABILITY).

Here is my code:

```
Socket socket = new(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

IPAddress hostIP = Dns.GetHostAddresses(host)[0];
IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new(hostIP, port);

socket.Connect(ipEndPoint);

SslStream sslStream = new(new NetworkStream(socket));
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(host);

byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

int bytesReceived = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
string response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesReceived);

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(response); // * OK IMAP4 ready
            
buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("LOGIN username@gmail.com password\r\n"); 

sslStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

bytesReceived = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesReceived);

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(response); // LOGIN BAD invalid command
```

Any suggestions on what could be wrong? The IMAP server requires connection through SSL and on port 993, both of them are provided. The host link is correct, they allow to log in and the login command should work. This must be an issue inside of the code.

Comment: You're sending the command `username@gmail.com` with tag `LOGIN`. That's not what you want. Have a look at [RFC 9051](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc9051), particularly section 8.

Comment: I have completely forgotten the prefix in front of the command. Thanks, wouldn't have figured it out so simply without your help!